# How to read up on what's on topic in-app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

When I join a new site I don't want my first question to be closed as off-topic. On the web I can navigate the help labyrinth to arrive at an answer, but I can't find that info in-app, nor a link to the help.

I think it's natural to have this close at hand when writing one's first question on a new site.

Unless it's already in here somewhere, I'd like to request it

Comment: @PolyGeo you're right, there it was